# Owl carousel 2: background image doesn't load in time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I've created an Owl Carousel using 2.0.0b4, with images as background styles in divs, like this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item" style='background-image: url("http://example.com/image_1.jpg");'></div>
  <div class="item" style='background-image: url("http://example.com/image_2.jpg");'></div>
  <div class="item" style='background-image: url("http://example.com/image_3.jpg");'></div>
  ...more...
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var owl = $(".owl-carousel")
      owl.owlCarousel({
        // loop: true,
        nav: true,
        items: 4,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items: 2,
                slideBy: 2
            },
            480:{
                items:3,
                slideBy: 3
            },
            768:{
                items:4,
                slideBy: 4
            }
        }
      })
    })
</script>
```

Works pretty well, and all of the responsive qualities of OC2 are working fine.  Only trouble: every time you scroll the carousel, the images enter the stage blank, only to draw their backgrounds afterwards all at once.  So you get this ugly flash as they load (I think this is separate from lazy loading).

This happens both when you scroll forward, and when you scroll back to divs you've already seen; it's as if the divs only render after they're in place and all animation has already occurred.

Ideas?

Comment: Don't you need to give the inner `div`s one of the owl-carousel item classes?

Comment: Hi Jay; still happening with `class='item'`.  Are there any other classes which you mean?  (I updated the question to reflect this.)  Thanks for looking!

Comment: There's a comment on this similar question that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346288/owlcarousel-preload-image-in-background

Comment: @isherwood, thanks, that was a good lead, and moved me forward.  I increasingly think this issue is separate from lazy loading, though.  I edited my question.

Comment: Hmm. Can I ask why you're declaring a variable rather than just  `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({...` ? Also, you missed the `;` after the variable decleration.

Comment: Sure; the variable is mostly a style thing, so I can call functions on the carousel at other points.  And semicolons are optional in javascript :) http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: Optional, but *highly* recommended. :)

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your css file:

```
.owl-item {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```